# How did syncronized block differentiate between lock object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I was creating an application like BookMyShow and wanted to lock on the seat at the code level. Please note I understand the lock is better on the database level but I was trying it for my knowledge.

So My problem was if multiple users trying to book the same seat then only there should be a lock otherwise all of them should be allowed to book the seat.

I have attached my code below. Please note I have made all things hardcoded just for simplicity for asking questions only.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        CriticalSection criticalSection = new CriticalSection();
        Runnable runnable = new MyThread(criticalSection);
        Runnable runnable1 = new MyThread(criticalSection);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable1);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

    }
}
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private CriticalSection criticalSection;
    private static AtomicInteger atomic = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public MyThread(CriticalSection criticalSection) {
        this.criticalSection = criticalSection;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Seat seat = new Seat(0);
        criticalSection.bookSeat(seat);
    }
}
public class Seat {

    private int seatId;

    public int getSeatId() {
        return seatId;
    }

    public Seat(int seatNumber) {
        this.seatId = seatNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
}
public class CriticalSection {
    public void bookSeat(Seat seat) {
        synchronized (seat) {
            System.out.println("This is my seat and my seat number us");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("My Seat Number is " + seat.getSeatId());
        }
    }
}
```

So As per logic inside the synchronized block only one thread should come as seat object is the same. but When I run the above code, both the threads enter inside the synchronized block. I do not understand on which basis synchronized differentiate between monitor objects. Please help me understand it.

Comment: `as seat object is the same.` Its not. Each thread creates its own `Seat` object.

Comment: As you can see in Seat class I have override the equals and hashcode and make sure that every object is same. Then on which basis It is saying it is different object?

Comment: They are _equal_, but not the same object.

Comment: Ok. But that is my original question How it diffentiate between object?

Comment: @tkausl Thanks for your answer. Now I get the clarity. Synchronized block uses == or memory address comparison instead of functionality comparison (using equals). That is why when we have two objects with the same value it does not lock them.

Answer (score 0):

> So As per logic inside the synchronized block only one thread should come as seat object is the same

`synchronized` *uses* object references to decide on the monitors. Overriding `equals` and `hashCode` don't make the two `Seat` objects *equal* for `synchronized`.

See the example below:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        var ref1 = Long.valueOf(123); // objects are cached in value range -128 to 127 (both inclusive)
        var ref2 = Long.valueOf(123);

       System.out.println("Reference Check: " + (ref1 == ref2));

        System.out.println("Ref1 System Id: " + System.identityHashCode(ref1));
        System.out.println("Ref2 System Id: " + System.identityHashCode(ref2));

        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (ref1) {
                System.out.println("Monitor Ref1 ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                    System.out.println("Done with ref1..");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

        }).start();

        System.out.println("Towards Ref2..");

        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (ref2) {
                System.out.println("Monitor Ref2 ");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.out.println("Done with ref2");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }

        }).start();

    }
}
```

**Output**:

```java
Reference Check: true
Ref1 System Id: 918221540
Ref2 System Id: 918221540
Towards Ref2..
Monitor Ref1 
// Waiting for release on ref1 for 4 secs
Done with ref1..
Monitor Ref2 
Done with ref2
```

If you change the definiton of `ref2` to:
`var ref2 = Long.valueOf(223);`

The Output is:

```java
Reference Check: false
Ref1 System Id: 918221540
Ref2 System Id: 2055281021
Towards Ref2..
Monitor Ref1 
// No wait here, The ref2 thread starts immediately
Monitor Ref2 
Done with ref2
Done with ref1..
```